# What the HTML 5 alternative to using the rules attribute for table element?

Tags: css, html

When using the rules attribute on this table element

`<table id="data" style="margin-top: 10px;border: 1px solid black; width:100%" rules="all">`

I get the following warning:

> Attribute (rules) is obsolete. Its use is discouraged in HTML5 documents.

What is the HTML 5 alternative for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[From here](http://html.com/attributes/table-rules/)

> **What does `<table rules="">` do?**
>
> Was used to specify the display of internal borders between rows and colums. This attribute has been deprecated. **Use CSS to style table borders instead**.

So there is no HTML5 alternative, just CSS alternative:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

table td {
  text-align: center;
}

.frame-box {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.frame-void {
  border: none;
}

.rules-none td {
  border: none;
}

.rules-all td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.rules-all td:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

.rules-all td:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

.rules-all tr:first-child td {
  border-top: none;
}

.rules-all tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.rules-cols td {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.rules-rows td {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.border-2,
.border-2 td {
  border-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
"&lt;TABLE BORDER=2 RULES=NONE FRAME=BOX&gt;"

<table class="rules-none border-2 frame-box">
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
</table>

"&lt;TABLE BORDER=2 FRAME=VOID RULES=ALL&gt;"
<table class="border-2 frame-void rules-all">
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
</table>

"&lt;TABLE BORDER=2 RULES=COLS FRAME=BOX&gt;"
<table class="border-2 frame-box rules-cols">
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
</table>

"&lt;TABLE BORDER=2 RULES=ROWS FRAME=BOX&gt;"
<table class="border-2 frame-box rules-rows">
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How would one incorporate the different values that rules had with CSS?

Comment: @Potterapple Please check all possibilities how to apply `border` to element. I have updated my answer with example code.

Answer (score 1):

HTML 5 demands that you replace the `rules` attribute with CSS attributes.
Source: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_rules.asp